# Android: How to lauch an app from browser?

Tags: android

I want to launch an activity when a link is clicked on android browser.
I have followed the instructions provided by the [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) .
When I open the browser and click on the link, the play store is lauched.

This is my href code contained in the html page:

```
intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=test;package=com.exekon.appbrowser.MainActivity;end
```

this and this is the code in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="test" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Can anyone proved me an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [zxing source code](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml#99) mentioned in the instructions you used:

```
    <data android:scheme="test" android:host="scan" android:path="/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the scheme definition into the [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml#97)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="zxing" android:host="scan" android:path="/"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

you must use something like:

```
  <data android:scheme="test" android:host="scan" android:path="/"/>
```